# How to change weeks/years/months to days in multiple component in angular?

Tags: angular, input

I am creating a medical form app which records patients information. here i  have duration for certain conditions as pain, redness and such [image: Image from app]

How to do it easy way so i can use same function returning different values for multiple medical conditions?
Should i create different function for each of these input types?
how to do this? i am new to angular so help me anyone

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that you can define an array of "conditions" (an array of objects) some like

```
conditions=[
   {value:1,text:"Decreased Vision",durations:[
                   {value:1,text:"Year"},{value:2,text:"Month"}]},
   {value:2,text:"Pain",durations:[
        {value:1,text:"Year"},{value:2,text:"Month",value:3,text:"Day}]},
   ...
]
```

Then, use a [FormArray](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray) and when iterate use this array

```
<div formArrayName="patienDetail">
   <tr *ngFor="let group of patienDetail.controls;let i=index; let [formGroup]="i">
      <td>
        <select formControlName="case1">
           <option *ngFor="let duration of conditions[i].durations"
             [value]="duration.value">{{duration.text}}>
        </select>
      </td>
   ...
   </tr>
</div>
```